# react-router link router.createHref is not a function error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I am creating a header which shows sign in / sign up link if the user is not already signed in or a sign out link if a user is already signed in

Here is my header component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router';

class Header extends Component {
  renderLinks() {
    if(this.props.authenticated) {
      return (
        <li className="nav-item">
          <Link to="/signout" className="nav-link">Sign Out</Link>
        </li>
      );
    }
    else {
      return (
        [
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/signin" className="nav-link">Sign In</Link>
          </li>,
          <li className="nav-item">
            <Link to="/signup" className="nav-link">Sign Up</Link>
          </li>     
        ]
      );
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <nav className="navbar navbar-light">
        <Link to="/" className="navbar-brand">Redux Auth</Link>
        <ul className="nav navbar-nav">
            {this.renderLinks()}
        </ul>
      </nav>
    );
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return { authenticated: state.auth.authenticated };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

I am getting the following error in the browser

Warning: Failed Context Types: Required context `router.push` was not specified in `Link`. Check the render method of `Header`.

Uncaught TypeError: router.createHref is not a function

I am using react router version 2.0.1

Why am I facing this issue? What does this error mean?

Comment: Show the code where you are using `router.createHref`

Comment: I did not use it anywhere. I think the code transpiled into es5 is using it near link tags. Not sure.

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the code in `<Router></Router>` and are you sure, you have handled `/` route?

Comment: instead of `react-router`, try using `react-router-dom`, from where the `Link` is imported.

Comment: @SuryaPurohit's commend about using `react-router-dom` fixed the issue for me!

Comment: Would be great if you accept the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`react-router` does not provide `Link`, you need to use `react-router-dom` for this.

Replace

```
import { Link } from 'react-router';
```

with

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
```

That'll work for you.